# UITableViewController can not set delegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, delegates

simply I have add UITableViewController to my storyboard

and set its class to file called CategoriesList :-

ScreenShot 1 :-
[image]

ScreenShot 2 :-
[image]

```
@interface CategoriesList : UITableViewController {

    NSArray *CategoryArray;


}

@end
```

but I keep getting

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CategoriesList setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9bfbd29370'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Solution

the Problem was :

in prepareForSegue method on UIViewController Which has the Button to the UITableViewController I am setting delegates to self for other view controller without Specify the segue name

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    AddMapAddress *MapAddress = [segue destinationViewController];
    MapAddress.delegate = self;
    MapAddress.AnnotationTitle = Name_Txt.text;

}
```

the Solution:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MapSegue"]) {
    AddMapAddress *MapAddress = [segue destinationViewController];
    MapAddress.delegate = self;
    MapAddress.AnnotationTitle = Name_Txt.text;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `UITableViewController` you don't need to specify neither a `delegate` or a `dataSource` because this is already done internally. In other words, `UITableViewController` consists basically of an ordinary `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` which already has its `delegate` and `dataSource` set to the parent controller. This is stated at Apple's docs:

> Subclass UITableViewController when your interface consists of a table view and little or no other content. *Table view controllers already adopt the protocols you need to manage your table view's content and respond to changes*.

So, just remove those referencing outlets to `delegate` and `dataSource` and you should do fine.

Comment: I did and still getting same error also I have delete the nib and add new one again without adding anything just set the class name and still getting same error

Comment: I have create new project and add UIViewController with ban to UITableViewController and its work fine but I do same steps in my projects I will not work